# Executing .sh file at raspberry using paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, sh, paramiko

I have to refresh the chromium page at a raspberrypi remotelly, I managed to run a .py file but the .sh it's not executing.

If I execute on the raspberry itself, the refresh works perfectly.

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=hostname,username=username, password=password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("bash /home/pi/refresh.sh'")

for line in stdout:
    print (line.strip('\n'))
 
client.close()
```

Here is the .sh file:

```
WID=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class chromium|head -1)
xdotool windowactivate ${WID}
xdotool key ctrl+F5
```

Does anyone have any idea of what might be happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say it's because the shell session doesn't have access to the X session. E.g. the `DISPLAY` env var won't be set, etc.You can try to isolate the issue by seeing if a dummy shell script that just writes something to a file is executed fine via SSH or not. Then you'd know the issue has to be something relating to X and SSH being used together.

Comment: you were right, I added DISPLAY=:0 to the .sh file and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by adding DISPLAY=:0 on the beginning of the .sh commands, example:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xdotool key F5
```